# Mounting cue/bin files

Tags: macos, finder, mount, automount

There [are](http://www.command-tab.com/2005/04/10/dealing-with-bincue-files-on-a-mac/) [many](http://forums.bit-tech.net/showthread.php?t=133366) [suggestions](http://www.mehtanirav.com/2008/08/22/bin-and-cue-files-combine-to-iso-on-mac-os-x) on the internet on how to use cue/bin files on a Mac.

Is there a native way of mounting cue or bin files and seeing them as Volumes in Finder?

Alternatively, are there any tools—in the vain of [Daemon Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_Tools) on a Windows machine—that provide this functionality?

*I would very much like avoid converting the files I have.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stuffit Expander](http://www.stuffit.com/mac-expander.html) (Select **StuffIt Expander Only** if you want to download it from that site, dont get any adware crap) can open bin files, and from what I remember cue files are just information maps about bin files.

I forget if you can view them as Volumes, but that seems like a secondary concern, converting them is a *lengthy* process if you have more than a few files.

Comment: Actually, I've just found out by trying that Unarchiver can do the same (i.e. extract). Hopefully someone will be able to find out how to *mount* them.

Comment: Does it work for the CUE files that are audio?

Comment: Its been a few years(5), but if I remember correctly the CUE files referred to here dont actually have the data, just a reference to the data, so if that is all you have its probably not what you are looking for, but I would do some additional googling.

Comment: This is a different kind of .bin file. StuffIt Expander expands MacBinary files, which used the .bin extension but have no associated .cue file. CD images are a .bin image (which is *not* in MacBinary format, but rather a dump of the track data from the CD) and a .cue file containing the cue sheet (track information, basically the disc's Table of Contents).

Answer (score 25):

I use binchunker to convert .bin/.cue files to a single .iso file on my Mac. You can obtain binchunker via Homebrew or Macports.

Here's some more info from the manpage:

```
bchunk - CD image format conversion from bin/cue to iso/cdr

SYNOPSIS
       bchunk [-v] [-p] [-r] [-w] [-s] <image.bin> <image.cue> <basename>

DESCRIPTION
       bchunk converts a CD image in a ".bin / .cue" format (sometimes ".raw / .cue") to a set of .iso and .cdr tracks.

       The  bin/cue  format is used by some non-Unix cd-writing software, but is not supported on most other cd-writing pro-
       grams.

       image.bin is the raw cd image file. image.cue is the track index file containing track types and  offsets.   basename
       is used for the beginning part of the created track files.

       The  produced .iso track contains an ISO file system, which can be mounted through a loop device on Linux systems, or
       written on a CD-R using cdrecord.  The .cdr tracks are in the native CD audio format. They can be either written on a
       CD-R using cdrecord -audio, or converted to WAV (or any other sound format for that matter) using sox.

       It  is  advisable  to  edit  the  .cue  file to either MODE2/2352/2048 or MODE2/2352/2324 depending on whether an ISO
       filesystem or a VCD is desired, respectively.  The format itself does not contain this feature and  in  an  ambiguous
       case it can only guess.
```

Comment: `brew install bchunk` for those with homebrew

Comment: `port install bchunk` for those with macports

Comment: Works great, thanks. I used this tool to convert Audio CD to wav files via `bchunk -w <image.bin> <image.cue> <basename>` and then wav to mp3 with iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Control+Click (right click) on the .bin file and open with Disk Utility?

Comment: I have, Disk Utility pops out but doesn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

I've just used Unarchiver and its extracted all the files in the .bin and i've been able to get the .wmv files that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Daemon tools free trial for OSX to mount bin file.

Comment: Hi Welcome to AskDifferent, I find if a question is worth answering it is worth upvoting.  Also some instructions and a link may get you more upvotes.