# How to make bin + cue image of audio CD under macOS

Tags: macos, audio, software-recommendation, optical-drive

I want to make a bin and cue files of my audio cd. On Windows I use PowerISO but on macOS I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `mkcue` or `bchunk` which are easily installed with brew.sh framework? https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179113/5472

Comment: For now I’ll close as dupe of a question pointing to XLD. Any edit to the body of the question will review the hold.